# Is it possible to abortively close a socket without sending an RST?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, tcp, winsock

I have a connected socket that I want to abortively close, but I do not want an RST to be sent to the other end. Can this be done?

Comment: You could disconnect the local machine from the remote until the TCP connection times out on the remote machine. [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136642/how-to-make-a-tcp-socket-time-out) is essentially that approach, but on *nix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

'Abortively close' == RST.

Even if the actual abortive close didn't send it immediately, TCP is obliged to send it on receipt of any other traffic for the connection, including data, ACKs, or even the peer's closing FIN.